# Spring Authorization Server use additional parameters from authorization request for login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

So basically, what I want is that following request:

`http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=test-client&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized&scope=message.read&state=someState?color=red`

is for example redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:9000/login?color=red`, so that I can access the color parameter for rendering the login page. The color parameter does not necessarely have to be in the URL, it should just be acessible in Thymeleaf.

It this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to accomplish this is to provide a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` that reads the parameter `color` and adds it to a redirect to `/login`. I have [an example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/eae6630599c139ddab3a1e9060a124fd47224059/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/security/FederatedIdentityAuthenticationEntryPoint.java#L61) that does something like this in the Federated Identity sample. Your implementation would be simpler in that you only want to append `?color=...` to `/login`, and don't require any of the other code in that example.

You can see the entry point applied [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/eae6630599c139ddab3a1e9060a124fd47224059/samples/federated-identity-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/security/FederatedIdentityConfigurer.java#L109-L112).